# Getting x and y position of PygAnimation object for collision detection

Tags: python, animation, pygame, collision-detection

I am about to create a crossy road-like game with an animated PygAnimation object (frog) and need to find the x and y position of the object in order to check for collision with enemies (lose condition) and the treasure (win condition). The animation itself is working:

```
if moveUp or moveDown or moveLeft or moveRight:
            if direction == UP:
                animObjs['back_walk'].blit(windowSurface, (x, y))
            elif direction == DOWN:
                animObjs['front_walk'].blit(windowSurface, (x, y))
            elif direction == LEFT:
                animObjs['left_walk'].blit(windowSurface, (x, y))
            elif direction == RIGHT:
                animObjs['right_walk'].blit(windowSurface, (x, y))
```

The AnimObjs are loaded into a dictionary but I can't access the x and y values of each character. I feel there is a simple solution to it but I am pretty new to programming and havent't found it out so far. The enemies are part of a NonPlayerCharacter(GameObject) class and the x and y values are just accessed with image_path, self.x_pos and self.y_pos. But with the animation, I don't seem to be able to access it the same way because the animations seem to be treated differently.

The following code is within the run game loop and merely serves to upload the gifs for the standing and the moving conditions:

```
    front_standing = pygame.image.load('frog_front.gif')
    back_standing = pygame.image.load('frog_back.gif')
    left_standing = pygame.image.load('frog_left.gif')
    right_standing = pygame.transform.flip(left_standing, True, False)

    playerWidth, playerHeight = front_standing.get_size()

    # creating the PygAnimation objects for walking in all directions
    animTypes = 'back_walk front_walk left_walk'.split()
    animObjs = {}
    animObjs['back_walk'] = pyganim.PygAnimation('frog_back_walk.gif')
    animObjs['front_walk'] = pyganim.PygAnimation('frog_front_walk.gif')

    animObjs['left_walk'] = pyganim.PygAnimation('frog_left_walk.gif')                                  

    # create the right-facing sprites by copying and flipping the left-facing sprites
    animObjs['right_walk'] = animObjs['left_walk'].getCopy()
    animObjs['right_walk'].flip(True, False)
    animObjs['right_walk'].makeTransformsPermanent()

    moveConductor = pyganim.PygConductor(animObjs)
    direction = DOWN # player starts with facing down (front)
```

The enemy class is the following:

class NonPlayerCharacter(GameObject):
SPEED = 10

```
def __init__(self,image_path, x, y, width, height):
    super().__init__(image_path, x, y, width, height)

def move(self, max_width):
    # automating of movement
    if self.x_pos <= 20:
        self.SPEED = abs(self.SPEED)
    elif self.x_pos >= max_width - 40:
        self.SPEED = -abs(self.SPEED)
    self.x_pos += self.SPEED
```

The enemies are just moving across the screen from the left to the right and this is how each enemy is accessed:

enemy_0 = NonPlayerCharacter("enemy.png", 20, 600, 50, 50)

I would really appreciate your help. I think it is only a minor thing. :-)

Comment: I was actually thinking that maybe I could create a rectangle on the object and then use pygame.rect.colliderect to check for a collision.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [pygAnimation source](https://github.com/asweigart/pyganim/blob/master/pyganim/__init__.py), you could use `.getRect()`, and then position that to the last-used `x,y` of the previous blit.  It looks like pygAnimations do not store the position internally.

However, the `getRect()` returns the *maximal* width & height of *all* animation frames, which may not be what you want for collisions. Particularly if the sprite size changes significantly during the animation sequence.

So, *maybe* something like this would do, using the `getCurrentFrame()`:

```
def getCurrentRect( position, animation ):
    """ Get the positioned rect of the current pygAnimation frame """
    current_image = animation.getCurrentFrame()
    rect = current_image.get_rect()
    rect.topleft = position                       # do you draw at top-left?
    return rect
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really helpful for my purposes!